# binding difficulty in datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am facing some difficulty in binding data in the grid.

**My data**:

<kbd>Time</kbd>       <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>2</kbd>    
  <kbd>00:00</kbd>      <kbd>,</kbd>          <kbd>,</kbd>     
  <kbd>00.30</kbd>      <kbd>,</kbd>          <kbd>,</kbd>     
  <kbd>01:00</kbd>      <kbd>,</kbd>          <kbd>,</kbd>     
  <kbd>01:30</kbd>      <kbd>,</kbd>          <kbd>,</kbd>     
  <kbd>02:00</kbd>      <kbd>,</kbd>          <kbd>,</kbd>     
  <kbd>02:30</kbd>      <kbd>,</kbd>          <kbd>,</kbd>

..etc.

**My code**:

```
public partial class data : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data1();
    }
    public void data1()
    {
        List<MyKVP> obj1 = new List<MyKVP>();

        List<string> str = new List<string>() { "Time", "1", "2" };

        List<string> str1 = new List<string>() { "00:00", "00:30", "01:00", "01:30", "02:00", "02:30", "03:00", "03:30", "04:00" };

        for (int count = 0; count < str1.Count; count++)
        {
            MyKVP obj = new MyKVP();
            if (count == 0)
            {
                obj.Key="0";

                for (int i = 0; i < str.Count; i++)
                {
                    Value o = new Value();
                    o.name = str[i];
                    obj.value.Add(o);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                obj.Key = Convert.ToString(count);

                Value o = new Value();
                o.name = ":";
                obj.value.Add(o);
            }
            obj1.Add(obj);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = obj1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
public class MyKVP
{
    public MyKVP()
    {
        value = new List<Value>();
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}
public class Value
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting only the keys in the grid not the list of values I have in the list.

my xmal

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
```

Comment: What's your question?  Are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: im not getting any error, its displaying only the key not the values in the list

Comment: Right, but you have to tell us.

Comment: You need to show us your `XAML` code as well.

Comment: ok. i will update in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to configure your GridView manually, so I would try something like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="---"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="---">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("value") %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItem  %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The GridView will not natively bind to a complex type like a generic List. If you add the following to your MyKVP object you will start to see the content of your value property.

```
public string ValueAsCsv
{
  get
  {
    return string.Join(",", value.Select(x => x.name));
  }
}
```